# How to generate the Site Usage Report using PowerShell or CSOM code?

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom, site-usage

I want to generate the details section which are displayed under Home > Usage > SharePoint Site Usage. Is it possible to generate the details using PowerShell/CSOM? The details which I am looking for is as below:

[image]

Kindly provide the link/reference where can I get guidance to generate the above details using PowerShell/CSOM code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not available through CSOM or PowerShell. If you look at the page, it uses a rest api to load the data and authentication with the fedauth cookie.

If I google the endpoint, it doesn't seem to be documented. So it's probably a use at your own risk endpoint.

The api url looks like this:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/sites/tentant.sharepoint.com,d0752114-7a09-4d94-be06-38beb572ad48,82fe4f03-221b-4fc7-b17b-e35980af49b7/oneDrive.getActivitiesByInterval?startDateTime=2018-04-24T11:51:39.728Z&endDateTime=2018-07-23T00:00:00.000Z&interval=day
```

If you are able to authenticate, it should be fairly easy to do a get request and get the data.